# widget Popup in backoffice not showing [OutConnections always null]

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

Is there any rule for widget-connection?

I created action on BackOffice, when I click on the action I want to show popup so I created a widget for popup and below my code 
When I get the current widget I got widget.getOutConnection() is empty ??

```
<widget-connection sourceWidgetId="STUB_com.yazeed.yazeedfulfillmentbackoffice.actions.fulfillmentaction"
    outputId="fulfillmentContext" targetWidgetId="warehousingFulfillmenttPopup" inputId="consignmentInput" />
```

This my action

```
<action-definition id="com.yazeed.yazeedfulfillmentbackoffice.actions.fulfillmentaction"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.hybris.com/schema/cockpitng/action-definition.xsd">
    <name>fulfillment.action</name>
    <actionClassName>com.yazeed.yazeedfulfillmentbackoffice.actions.FulfillmentAction</actionClassName>
    <inputType>de.hybris.platform.ordersplitting.model.ConsignmentModel</inputType>
    <outputType>de.hybris.platform.ordersplitting.model.ConsignmentModel</outputType>
    <settings>
        <setting key="viewMode" default-value="iconAndText" />
    </settings>
    <sockets>
        <output id="fulfillmentContext"  type="java.lang.Object" />
    </sockets>
</action-definition>
```

This my widgit file

```
<widget-definition id="com.yazeed.yazeedfulfillmentbackoffice.widgets.fulfillmenttype"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.hybris.com/schema/cockpitng/widget-definition.xsd" >
    <name>Fulfillment Type</name>
    <sockets>
        <input type="de.hybris.platform.ordersplitting.model.ConsignmentModel" id="consignmentInput" />
        <output type="java.lang.Object" id="confirmOutput" />
    </sockets>
    <view src="fulfillmenttype.zul" />
    <keywords>
        <keyword>Fulfillment Type</keyword>
    </keywords>
    <controller class="com.yazeed.yazeedfulfillmentbackoffice.widgets.FulfillmentController"/>
</widget-definition>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you created the widget in custom-backoffice-widgets.xml file with widget id="warehousingFulfillmenttPopup" and WidgetDeifintionId="com.yazeed.yazeedfulfillmentbackoffice.widgets.fulfillmenttype"